# How to avoid cartesian-product in a cypher query and still create links between objects?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, cartesian-product

I imported a table with thousands of Equipments. Then imported another table with types of equipments, which contain around 20 types.

When I wrote the cypher query below to associate them, Neo4j warned me about a cartesian product. Is there a better way to create the associations? Should I have done it during the CSV import?

```
MATCH (te:Equipment_Type),(e:Equipment)
WHERE te.type_id = e.type_id
CREATE (e)-[:TYPE_OF]→(te)
```

**Update**

I tryed what Brian sugested, during the CSV import, and worked like a charm.

1. Imported the Equipment Types first;
2. Then created and index on Equipment(type_id);
3. Modified the code to search during CSV import.

From Neo4j Console:

> Added 100812 labels, created 100812 nodes, set 414307 properties,
>   created 100812 relationships, statement executed in 33902 ms.

The Code:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Equipment(type_id)

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://localhost/Equipments.csv" AS row
MERGE (e:Equipment {eqp_id: row.eqp_id, name: row.name, type_id: row.type_id})
WITH e, row
MATCH (te:Equipemnt_Type)
WHERE te.type_id = row.type_id
CREATE (e)-[:TYPE_OF]->(te)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the size of data that you're talking about it's not a big deal, especially if you have indexes on `Equipment_Type:type_id` and `Equipment:type_id`.  It's warning you because a cartesian project in a query can seem quick when you first write it on a small dataset and then grow quickly as you get more data.

But yes, creating the relationships during the CSV import would be the best way to approach it, probably.